# PHP / Insert foreach in query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

Im trying to fill query with array. As I know I can display array with function `foreach();` but im not able to put it in mysql query
Im trying to do something like this:

```
<?php
$arr = array("arr_1", "arr_2", "arr_3", "arr_4");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = '1'".
foreach($arr as $arr) {
    echo "AND user = '".$arr++."'";
}
." ORDER BY id";
?>
```

Script have to display this as:
`$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = '1' AND user = 'arr_1' AND user = 'arr_2' AND user = 'arr_3' AND user = 'arr_4'");`

But this doesnt work becouse you cant put `foreach()` in `mysql_query();`.
So what I need is script that do the same thing ( display array in query string )

Thanks.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: user=1 and user=2 ? do you mean __OR__

Comment: Can `user` be equal to both '1' and 'arr_1'? Perhaps you just need to use `IN` here, like `SELECT * FROM users WHERE user IN (1, 'arr_1', ...)`?

Comment: what is $arr++ if $arr='arr_1';

Comment: cant put foreach in mysql - but you can do `user IN ('arr_1','arr_2','arr_3')`  BTW this does __OR__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to add multiple conditions from array, do concatenation instead of echo

```
<?php
$arr = array("arr_1", "arr_2", "arr_3", "arr_4");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = '1'";
foreach($arr as $id) {
    $query .= "AND user = '".$id."'";
}
$query .= " ORDER BY id";
?>
```

Comment: You still need to replace the `.` with a `;` and I would say you have to add another whitespace before or after each iteration.

Comment: @insertusernamehere: didnt notice that, and i changed accordingly

Comment: It's a bit like back in school: "Find all mistakes in this code. Solve it with pen and paper.". :)

Comment: Still this query is likely to not return anything as `AND` is used which will fail for sure as no column will be equal to all of the values.

Comment: I just inserted OR insted of AND and change it a bit and its working perfect :) Thanks :)

Comment: @Andrew if this is the case use IN

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum i tried to use IN but it doest work OR works perfect :) but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but an alternative:

```
$arr = array("arr_1", "arr_2", "arr_3", "arr_4");

$arr_string="'".implode("','", $arr)."'"; // surround values in quotes

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user IN (".$arr_string.") ORDER BY id";
```